# Is it possible that my database flush when I use a Joomla CMS?

Tags: database, templates, joomla, content-management-system

It seem that my main template is empty all of the sudden.. I did not modify it.

Comment: Could be any kind of issue - without further information it's hard to say.  Could be a template issue, could be that someone got ahold of your configuration.php file, could be that the site is offline, could be that the database got emptied, could be anything!  We need more information.  Also when you say 'empty' do you mean nothing shows up?  Is the backend still there?  Are the articles still there?  Is the database empty?  Joomla doesn't flush the database.  You'd have to do that manually.

Comment: Template is NOT stored in database, so you should decide or you database is empty or there's an error in your php (see error log )

Answer (score 0):

@shershen was not accurate: 
it's true that the template files are under the templates folder, but, in Joomla 1.5 run the following sql:

```
select * from jos_extensions where type='template';
```

I had a template that was installed "half way" and I couldn't re-install it, so I deleted the relevant line from the extensions table - and only then I could re-install it!